# Is the random current model tight (in the sense of probability)?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, ising-model, spin-models, randomness

Let us consider the random current model (of the classical Ising model) on $\mathbb{Z}^d$. More specifically, we have probability measures $\mathbb{P}_L$ on the product space $\mathbb{N}^{E_L}$ where $E_L$ are the nearest-neighbor edges of the box $\Lambda_L = \{-L,...,L\}^d$, i.e., each edge has a current of nonnegative integer value. We can naturally extend this measure to $\mathbb{N}^{E_\infty}$ where $E_\infty$ are all the edges of $\mathbb{Z}^d$. Is this family of measures tight?

Indeed, for the random cluster model, the probability space is $\{0,1\} ^{E_\infty}$, which is compact and thus the probability measures are automatically tight. Of course, for the random current model, we could limit ourselves to take the "trace" of currents, i.e., $\hat{n} = 1\{ n > 0\}$ so that the probability measure is restricted to $\{0,1\} ^{E_\infty}$, and repeat the argument. However, can we consider the full space $\mathbb{N}^{E_\infty}$ (with discrete topology)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at least for $+$ and free boundary conditions; moreover, the limiting measures are translation invariant and ergodic. The proof is given in Section 2.2 of the paper

> *Random Currents and Continuity of Ising Model’s Spontaneous Magnetization*
>
> M. Aizenman, H. Duminil-Copin, V. Sidoravicius
>
> Communications in Mathematical Physics **334**, 719–742 (2015).

You can get the arXiv version [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.1937).

The argument is nice and not very difficult (basically, one reduces to expressions involving correlation functions of the Ising model, for which convergence is known; note also that you can always reduce attention to the variables encoding the parity of the current at each edge, since conditionally on this information, the law of the current is just a collection of independent Poisson random variables conditioned on having the required parity), but it seems pointless to copy it here.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. This was actually the exact reference I was looking at when thinking about this. If I understand it correctly, the proof only proves that the probability measure $\mathbb{P}_L$ converges for cylinder events. Usually, we also need to tightness to show that $\mathbb{P}_L$ converges weakly to a probability, but I'm having some trouble seeing why $\mathbb{P}_L$ is tight.

Comment: Is it because if we regard $\mathbb{P}_L$ as probabilities on the parity function (values in $\{-1,1\}$), then they must be tight due to compactness. Since the currents are conditionally independent with respect to parity, they must also be tight? (I'm a bit fuzzy with the details regarding this part)

Comment: Yes, in the present case, they simply note that you can construct the infinite-volume measure as a measure on parity variables (for those, compactness is clear) and (for instance) two collections of independent Poisson random variables conditioned on taking odd, respectively even, values.